# Parsing a line in a text file that follows a static line

Tags: python, list, parsing, for-loop

I am new to python so any comments/suggestions are appreciated. I am trying to pull out usernames and roles from a text file and store them into a list so that I can write them to a separate file. The usernames are dynamic so I cannot simply start the parsing if that line begins with the id "admin" every time. The usernames are not on the same line every time as there is various lines of text prior so I start by searching for the only static line that starts with USERNAME and know that the usernames are on the next lines up until a blank (    ) line.

The text file looks something like the following:

```
(Dynamic lines of text..)

USERNAME    ROLE

user345    user

admin31414   admin

user113131   user

user34342   user

admin585   admin

user333   user

user599       user
```

Where I am having trouble is figuring out how to skip to the next line while parsing the file if the initial line starts with "username". I use file.next() but it just skips to the next line (no longer static) in the for loop and the IF statement fails. My current loop code is as follows:

```
for line in file:
    if line.startswith('USERNAME'):
        file.next()
```

As I stated before I am new to python so any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a boolean variable to remember when it should be recording user names and when it should not.

```
record = False
for line in file:
    if line.startswith('--END--'):  # so you don't catch any extra lines
        break  # this exits the loop
    if record:
        print line  # or whatever code you want to run on each username
    if line.startswith('USERNAME'):
        record = True  # this will be visible in the next loop iteration
```

You shouldn't call 'file.next' when you're already looping over 'file'. The loop will take care of calling 'next'. If you want to skip to the next iteration of the loop, use the 'continue' statement.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do is perform the test just before you loop again, for example:

```
found_username = False
for line in file:
    if found_username:
        # process line here
    if line.startswith('USERNAME'):
        found_username = True
```

Answer (score -1):

you could use splitlines to split all lines

```
with open(r"user.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    for eachLine in lines:
        if eachLine.startswith('USERNAME'):
            pass
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and splitlines() is a string method, not a file method. You might mean readlines() but it's no longer necessary.